# Trouble creating an array loop in Y86 Assembly

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, cpu-registers, y86

I need to create a program that sorts an array of integers into ascending order. Simple enough problem in C, and the code is given to us.

```
void bubble(int *data, int count)
{
int i, last;
for(last = count‐1; last>0;last‐‐)
{
for(i=0;i<last;i++)
if
(data[i+1] < data[i])
{
/* Swap adjacent elements */
int t=data[i+1];
data[i+1]=data[i];
data[i]=t;
}
}
}
```

but when I try to implement it into assembly, I get either

```
Error on line 90: Invalid line
Line 90, Byte 0x00d0: .comm *data,20,4      //data = memory location
```

or, if I comment that line out (I don't think I should) I get this

```
Error on line 39: Expecting ')'
Line 39, Byte 0x005a:   mrmovl (%edx,%ebx,4),%eax   //%eax = data[i]
Error on line 41: Expecting ')'
Line 41, Byte 0x0066:   mrmovl 4(%edx,%ebx,4),%edi  //%edi = data[i++]
Error on line 46: Expecting ')'
Line 46, Byte 0x0073:   mrmovl 4(%edx,%ebx,4),%edi  //%edi = data[i++]
Error on line 47: Expecting ')'
Line 47, Byte 0x0079:   rmmovl %edi, (%edx,%ebx,4)  //data[i] = data[i++]
Error on line 48: Expecting ')'
Line 48, Byte 0x007f:   rmmovl %eax, 4(%edx,%ebx,4) //data[i++] = data[i]
```

The following is my code as it stands:

```
    .pos 0

init:   irmovl Stack, %esp  //Set up stack pointer
    irmovl Stack, %ebp  //Set up base pointer
    call main       //call main program
    halt            //Terminate program

bubble: pushl %ebp      //setup
    rrmovl %esp, %ebp

    pushl %edx      //declaring *data
    mrmovl 8(%ebp), %edx        
    pushl %ecx      //declaring count
    mrmovl 12(%ebp), %ecx   
    pushl %ebx      //declaring i
    pushl %esi      //declaring last
    pushl %edi
    pushl %eax
    irmovl $1, %edi     //%edi = 1

    rrmovl %ecx,%esi    //last=count
    subl %edi,%esi      //last--

L1: 
    irmovl $0, %edi     //%edi = 0
    subl %edi,%esi      //last -= 0
    jle L9          //ends loop if last <= 0

    irmovl $0, %ebx     //i = 0
L2:
    rrmovl %ebx, %edi   //%edi = copy of i
    subl %esi,%edi      //%edi = i-last
    jge L8          //ends loop if i >= last

    mrmovl (%edx,%ebx,4),%eax   //%eax = data[i]
    irmovl $1, %edi         //%edi = 1
    mrmovl 4(%edx,%ebx,4),%edi  //%edi = data[i++]

    subl %eax,%edi      //%edi = data[i++]-data[i]
    jge L7          //cancel if statement if data[i++]>=data[i]

    mrmovl 4(%edx,%ebx,4),%edi  //%edi = data[i++]
    rmmovl %edi, (%edx,%ebx,4)  //data[i] = data[i++]
    rmmovl %eax, 4(%edx,%ebx,4) //data[i++] = data[i]

L7:
    irmovl $1, %edi     //%edi = 1
    addl %edi,%ebx      //i++
    jmp L2          //go to beginning of loop
L8:
    irmovl $1, %edi     //%edi = 1
    subl %edi,%esi      //last--
    jmp L1
L9:
    popl %ebx       //finish
    popl %esi
    popl %edi
    popl %eax
    popl %ebp

    ret




main:   pushl %ebp      //setup
    rrmovl %esp, %ebp

    pushl %ebx      //declaring *data
    mrmovl data, %ebx   
    pushl %esi      //declaring count
    mrmovl count, %esi  

    rmmovl %ebx, (%esp) //move data to be used by bubble
    rmmovl %esi, 4(%esp)    //move count to be used by bubble

    call bubble

    popl %ebx       //finish
    popl %esi
    popl %ebp

    ret


.comm data,20,4     //data = memory location
.align 4
count:  .long 5     //count = memory location 
data:   .long 2     //data array assignment
    .long 1
    .long 3
    .long 5
    .long 4

.pos 0x200
Stack: .long 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*y86* does not support the full *x86* effective address syntax with the index and scale, it only allows `displacement(base)`. You have to perform the address calculation yourself.

The *y86* assembler doesn't support `.comm` either, just define your data using `.long`